# Style text inside an HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, styles, textarea, highlight

My problem is that I have textarea and want to find a specified string and mark all of its occurences (something similar to what [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) does with regex matches).

This leads me to a more general question (see my question title) and I would like to learn if the following can be applied to parts of text inside a textarea:

- change font color
- change background color
- change font style (bold, italic)
- change font size

Should I use something which already exists (like [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/))?

I would also appreciate it if someone could explain the idea behind this (for example regex101.com has a textarea but also uses some span elements to highlight the matches)

Comment: you can not style segments within a textarea, it's all or none. Need to use other elements to do it.Inspect live html in your regex example will see the highlighting is in a `<pre>` tag

Comment: I think this might be a suitable answer? Although this is not Angular, you can still use content editable div to reach the same function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373933/angular-2-multiple-font-colors-in-a-textarea

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");
textArea.style.color = 'Red';
textArea.style.backgroundColor = 'Black';
```

Comment: This would change the color of the whole text, not a part of it. :-)

Comment: Correct. So you just want to apply that styling to only the text returned by the regex, correct

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: Here's something more in the right direction.... http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/9Y99F/

Comment: @mwilson I think that only change the color of the background rather than the text itself.