# Angular 2 multiple font colors in a textarea

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a text area with one string binded to it. With the text color as white by default.

```
<textarea style="background-color: black;color:#fff;" [(ngModel)]="outputText"></textarea>
```

The bound string contains multiple variables.

```
return this.outputText = this.test1 + " test1Stat" + this.test2 + " test2Stat" + this.test3 + " test3Stat";
```

What I want to do is, if test1 is less than 1, it should show "test1 test1Stat" in red, while everything else is in green.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to color part of the text in a textarea,
However-  you can try to use the 'contenteditable'  property instead.

It basically turns your div into a textbox,  and you can use html tags and such inside.

```css
.greenText{
color:green;}

div{
border:black solid 1px;
padding:20px;
}
```

```html
    <div contenteditable="true">text text <span class='greenText'>GREEN TEXT</span> more text that you can edit</div>
```

Comment: While not exactly what I would have liked, this seems like the best option in the current situation, thanks.